# Understanding the streams coupled with HTTP request in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, stream

Hello everyone I'm new on flutter and rigth now I'm trying to know how Stream work in flutter so I've done a little app to make it clear
this my service making GET resquest to a REST API (django rest framework ) :

```
class DataService {

  static Future loadJson(String url) async {

     await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));

     http.Response response = await http.get(url);
     if (response.statusCode == 200) {
       String content = response.body;
       var jsonResponse = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
       data = jsonResponse;
       print('$jsonResponse');

      } else {
         print('Request failed with status: ${response.statusCode}.');
   }
 }
}
```

To feed my StreamBuilder inside my class State with data from the API, I'm using a stream which call my service :

```
 class DataManager{
    Stream<List> get colistView async*{
         yield await DataService.loadJson(colis);
    }
  }
```

But I've got an issue calling **new DataManager.colistView** in the **StreamBuilder** when I run the app and switch several time on page from the same screen (page where stream is called include) its display **Bad State: stream has already been listened to.**
What to do? Ideas?

Put **new DataManager.colistView.asBroadcastStream()** in the StreamBuilder don't show data

I called like this:

```
      StreamBuilder(
        stream:new DataManager.colistView.asBroadcastStream(),
          builder:(context, snapshot){
             //return something if shapshot hasdata according to a connectionState
          }
      )
```

Its displays nothing on the screen page event after the full restart